# Pegar média no mysql com diversas condições

Tags: php, mysql

Estou montando um gráfico contendo a quantidade de CHATS que foram respondidos em determinado tempo, exemplo:

> 1-30s -> 20 chats respondidos
>
> 31-60s -> 66 chats respondidos
>
> 60-120s -> 4 chats respondidos

Estou confuso em como retornar isso utilizando uma query

A estrutura base da minha tabela é:

> ID | Titulo | Duração do chat
>
> 1  | Teste  | 20
>
> 2  | Teste2 | 66

Para pegar a média de duração, eu utilizo o código abaixo:

```
$filter['filtergt']['user_id'] = 0;           
$filterCombined = array_merge_recursive($filter,array('filtergt' => array('chat_duration' => 0),'filter' =>  array('status' => erLhcoreClassModelChat::STATUS_CLOSED_CHAT)));            
   return erLhcoreClassChat::getCount($filterCombined, 'lh_chat', 'AVG(chat_duration)');
```

Acredito que com subqueries resolva, mas não tenho certeza

obs: só a query resolve, ou a ideia, e eu implemento no sistema

Pegar todos os chats e fazer a verificação um a um do tempo de duração acredito não ser viável, pensando em quantidades grandes de chats existentes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, você consegue fazer isso apenas com SQL. Você pode utilizar a estrutura *case* para definir um valor comum entre os registros de cada intervalo e, posteriormente, realizar o agrupamento dos mesmos, calculando a quantidade de registros em cada grupo.

Por exemplo:

```
select
  case
    when duration between 0 and 30 then '0-30s'
    when duration between 31 and 60 then '30-60s'
    else '60-120s'
  end as tempo,
  count(*) as total
from atendimento
group by tempo
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/105682/7)</sup>

Comment: Olá, ele funciona corretamente, porém eu adicionei mais 2 condições (60-90 e 90-120) e por algum motivo, o quinto (que seria o "else") não é ativado, nem se eu colocar mais outras condições, só retorna as 4 primeiras, porém funciona corretamente com essa exceção

Comment: Faça um exemplo reproduzindo o que fez e poste o link.

Comment: aqui está http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56ac7/1/0

Comment: Não entendi o que está errado aí. O resultado pareceu certo.

Comment: Amigo, eu ia responder agora. Falha minha, não me atentei a ordem em que os registros retornaram, e achei que faltava um, está realmente correto, desculpe!